# Returning value from a case statement inside a function to another function

Tags: shell, switch-statement

I am trying to call a function which has a case statement, when user enters 1, this should return a value 1 to calling function and in turn the calling function continues for further commands to execute based on the return value.

```
#!/bin/bash   
continue_exec () {
 return_value=0
 select yes_no in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yes_no in
        Yes ) return_value=1;break;;
        No ) return_value=2;break;;
    esac
 done
 return $return_value   
}

dev_func () {
  exec_status=$( continue_exec )
  if [ "$exec_status" -eq 1 ]; then
     echo "data load"   
  else
    echo "do not load."
  fi            
}

 dev_func
```

but getting the below error

```
**line 18: [:integer expression expected**
```

What is it i am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In shell script `return` statement is responsible for returning a status.
You can catch the status by using `$?` next where you called your function.

```sh
#!/bin/bash   
continue_exec () {
  return_value=0
  select yes_no in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yes_no in
      Yes ) return_value=1;break;;
      No ) return_value=2;break;;
    esac
  done
  return $return_value
}

dev_func () {
  continue_exec
  exec_status=$?
  if [ "$exec_status" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "data load"   
  else
    echo "do not load."
  fi                
}

dev_func
```

But this case use `echo` instead. You can find the snippet below, and leave the `dev_func` function as it was.

```sh
continue_exec () {
  return_value=0
  select yes_no in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yes_no in
      Yes ) return_value=1;break;;
      No ) return_value=2;break;;
    esac
  done
  echo "$return_value"
}
```